# SQL Requests. Working with text boxes

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Not working request. What could be the problem? Before that he wrote through CommandText, all worked well.

Code:

```
        private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\HomePC\Desktop\Lab2 DB\Lab2 DB\ResearchDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM '"+comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+"' WHERE '"+ comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() +"' = '"+ textBox1.Text +"'", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Piyush Not a request. Not displayed in GridView if a simple request to register, all is working well.

Comment: your question is very much unclear? try to modified your question so it become answerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd help if you provided an error, but one obvious issue is that you're not opening the connection.

You can open the connection right after you set the `CommandType`.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
con.Open();
```

Also, I'd recommend parameterizing your query. It's more secure, and cuts down on potential typos.

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' WHERE '" +  comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' = @your_textbox_value", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@your_textbox_value", textBox1.Text);
    con.Open();

    ...
```

Comment: It's working with TextBox, but don't with ComboBoxes.